# page-flip.com - Making Flash Stage Smaller

Tags: html, css, flash

I'm after a way to make the size of the flash file smaller in height. I can change the width but the height seems to be relative to the size of the window its in?

http://www.bevelite.com.au/test

I'm using [page-flip.com](http://www.page-flip.com)

Comment: It's a bit vague. In the given link, what exactly are you trying to do? What height and width do you want your swf to be?

Comment: i want the swf to have a height of 420px and a width of 730px..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the pointers guys but as it turns out I needed to removed the reference to the 'brochure.js' file as it was a function to automatically calculate the height based on the height of the window minus the height of the footer. Bit strange this wasn't mentioned in the documentation..

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
```

Edit:

Following Evilpenguin's comment, of course if you are embedding a SWF you cannot recompile you will have to set this value externally from within the HTML embed (`scale="noscale"`).

Comment: I'm not sure he has access to the FLA to recompile the swf.. scale="none" should be added to the embed instead

Answer (score 0):

Can't figure out where exactly you do the embed. You should add `scale="none"` property to the embed tag.